# How do i automate the JCL

Tags: jenkins, jcl

How do i automate the JCL , I Run the JCL job to check whether any objects are in restricted state.  I want to excute the job using jenkins manually.

I Run the JCL job to check whether any objects are in restricted state.  I want to excute the job using jenkins manually.

Comment: If you have a scheduler software then you can schedule the job to run at the specified time and day. If you don't have such software then you need to code something like a cronjob that will submit the job at the intervals of your choice.